# I am getting 404 page not found error when share link on facebook

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook, meta

I am developing a web application where i need to share web link on facebook.

I have used facebook share button on my page. Below is the share button code which i am using.

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-type="button_count" data-share="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-href="http://www.housingsutra.com/news-events/the-standard-chunk-of-lorem">
```

and here is a my app id which i put into head.

```
<script>

      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '634793463291263',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.2'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

I also put following meta tags in the top of the page.

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="Housing Sutra" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.housingsutra.com/" /> 
    <meta property="og:image" content="" /> 
    <meta property="og:description" content="" />
```

There is two condition where i confused.

1. When I pass the URL for share button with **https** then its work fine but after clicking on that link from facebook it shows error.
2. When I pass the URL for share button with **http** it show authorization error on share box but the link which i share works fine and its not showing any error.

Please help.

Comment: did you check the fb app settings , website url or callback urls pointing to https ?

Comment: yes...i have checked all possibility...

Comment: This affects a bunch of people. Something is definitely wrong with their scraper. http://marketingland.com/facebook-sharing-bug-generates-404-errors-77242

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used facebook linter tool for checking your url:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Your site is not visible its, http protected , try taking url from another ip, you must be bypassing that
http://www.housingsutra.com/news-events/the-standard-chunk-of-lorem

When we go to this site it asks username password.
[image]

Comment: when i am passing url with http its work but on facebook share box it shows following error ======= || 401 Authorization Required
This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.
www.housingsutra.com ||======

Comment: What I meant is when you take http://www.housingsutra.com/news-events/the-standard-chunk-of-lorem from some other system you will not be able to see that page. It is asking Authorization.

Comment: The authorization username and password might be saved in your browser, or your IP adress must be bypassed from authorization.

Comment: Now goto https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ give your site url and click Fectch New Scrape Information and it will work

Comment: Thank you very much...its working now...but where i went wrong..i dont understand..can you please explain....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70109/discussion-between-abhiklpm-and-rahul-narhe).